# Random variables/probability distribution table

Tags: probability

A discrete random variable $X$ has the following distribution table.
In the table, the $x$ values are $-2, -1, 0, 1, 2$ and their coinciding values are $0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2$, and $0.3$ respectively.

a) Find the probability distribution table of the random variable $Y=X^2$

b) Compute $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$

c) Compute $E(X^2 - X + 1)$

I'm not sure how to begin with this problem. I think I start by squaring the $x$ values, but that means I would get $0, 1$, and $4$ on the table? And how exactly would I go about computing those alternate expected values? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fill out the table.

$\begin{array}{|r|r:r:r:r:r|l|} \hline X & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 
\\ \hdashline \mathsf P(X=x) & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\ \hdashline x\,\mathsf P(X=x) & -0.2 &-0.2 & 0 & 0.2 & 0.6 & \mathsf E(X)= 0.4 \\ \hline\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{|r|r:r:r|l|} \hline Y\textsf{ a.k.a. } X^2 & 0 & 1 & 4  \\ \hdashline \mathsf P(Y=y) \\ \hdashline y\,\mathsf P(Y=y) & & &  &\mathsf E(Y)=?\\ \hline \end{array}$

For $\mathsf E(X^2-X+1)$ recall the *Linearity of Expectation*.